# magento, how correctly create sql request to database used colleciton, AND condition

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

i have this code

```
$collection = mage::getModel('purchasemanagement/purchasemanagement')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToSelect('item_id')
            ->addFieldToFilter(
                array('title', 'content'),
                array(
                    array('like'=>'%$titlesearchtext%', 'like' => 'content2'),
                )
            )
            ->load(true);
```

i have this sql on result

```
SELECT `main_table`.`item_id` FROM `dk_purchase_management` AS `main_table` WHERE ((`title` LIKE 'content2') OR (`content` = ''))
```

how can i create AND condition?
for example

```
SELECT `main_table`.`item_id` FROM `dk_purchase_management` AS `main_table` WHERE ((`title` LIKE 'titlesearchtext' AND `content2` => 'content'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply AND condition like below:

```
$collection = mage::getModel('purchasemanagement/purchasemanagement')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToSelect('item_id')            
            ->addFieldToFilter('title', ['like' => '%titlesearchtext%'])
            ->addFieldToFilter('content2',['eq' => 'content'])
            ->load(true);
```

Hope this help to you.

Thanks,